# DOMPDF - background url (linux vs windows)

Tags: php, html, css, linux, dompdf

When I generate PDF from html, my img doesn't show on server linux.

In  Localhost, my image is getting displayed.

my code css :

```
background: red url("<?php echo __DIR__ ?/my_img.png");
```

But on server linux, it's not getting displayed
For Info :

If I write

```
<img src="<?php echo __DIR__ ?/my_img.png">
```

I see this image on both server.

**EDIT :**

**I need to repeat image (x and y)
So I don't insert a**

**I try this**

```
.myimg:after {
background: red url("<?php echo __DIR__ ?/my_img.png");
}
```

**But IMG is not getting displayed.
So I think DOMPDF can't interpret URL in background in CSS.**

An idea?

Comment: ... What? _"I see this img on both server.

But on server linux, he doesn't show."_ Does the image show when you use `__DIR__` or does it not show?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. EDIT UP. The problèm is the CSS not interpret I think

Comment: Is it a CSS file? If so, have you configured your server / client to parse php in the .css files?

Comment: Maybe the DOMPDF you use in your localhost is different from your DOMPDF in Server/Linux. Check it.

Comment: Same version. Because I use Zend Framework, the module in framework are identical.

Comment: Seems unrelated, maybe just an issue with your question, but you didn't appropriately close the PHP code.

Comment: My code php is in fact : background-image: url("<?php echo __DIR__ ?>/../../src/pdf/Controller/pdf/myimg.png");

Answer (score 0):

I find :

```
<img src='data:image/png;base64,<?php echo base64_encode(file_get_contents("myimg.png")); ?>'>
```

Its works!

Comment: That certainly should work (though watch out for [white space bug](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/issues/1016), fixed in 0.7.0). The direct reference to the image should work as well, but it's hard to debug without more info. Probably either a path issue or a permission issue.

Comment: Not a problem ' Path ' or ' permission ' bercause <img src=""> works. (permission is 755).

Comment: Which version of dompdf are you using. v0.5.1 did not have good support for the background short-hand declaration. In that version try separating your CSS out into `background-color: red; background-image: url("url("<?php echo __DIR__ ?/my_img.png");`. v0.6.0 or newer should be ok with the short-hand declaration.

Comment: OK. I don't have any issues with that styling. Moving beyond this point would require much more back-and-forth. Don't know if you want to do any more debugging beyond that since you've got a solution, but if you do head on over to the [support forum](http://groups.google.com/group/dompdf) or [start a chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/).